# Keycloak Spring Boot tokens not propagated from Zuul Proxy to Spring Boot Services

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, netflix-zuul, keycloak-services

I have Zuul Proxy and I have implemented keycloak-adapter in it with the following configuration in application.properties:

```
#Keycloak config
keycloak.realm=Development
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://<IP>:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.resource=example
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/api/*
keycloak.security-constraints[1].authRoles[0]=operator
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/api/*
keycloak.expose-token=true

# Keycloak Enable CORS
keycloak.cors = true

zuul.ignored-headers=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie, Set-Cookie
```

The client for the proxy is public client.
When I access it I can see the keycloak login page and It is okay, but when it redirect me to the services that also have keycloak-adapter with the same configuration (except the zuul configuration) and also a public client I am receiving a Bad Request and No State Cookie in the Service logs.

One thing that I have noticed is that when I access Swagger documentation on the proxy everything is blocked because of the CORS even the documentation from the services that does not have implemented keycloak.

EDIT: When I am making the same stuff from GUI where I am sending token, it is working as I want.